# How to activate the function of a hidden input?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a simple script that allow users to enter a value in an input. Those values will then be concatenated to form a URL, which will open the page in an iframe.

It's working fine... but if I want to hide the result on the third input (complete URL), and only show the users the value they entered, I cannot trigger the third input to display the iframe page.

Please see this code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="actpart1" value="116-2"/>

<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="actpart2" value="116-261"/>
    
<button onClick="javascript: window.open('document.getElementById('acturl').value);">Go</button>


<input type="text" id="acturl" value=""/ hidden>


<iframe id="actframe" src="" loading="lazy" width="100%" height="735" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>

<script>
$('#actpart1, #actpart2, #section10a').bind('keypress blur', function() {
    $('#acturl').val('https://sample.app/' + $('#actpart1').val() + '/' +
                            $('#actpart2').val() + '.pdf');
});
</script>

<script>
$('input#acturl').on('propertychange paste keyup',function(){
  var url = this.value;
  $('#actframe').attr('src', url);
});
$('input#acturl').keyup();
</script>
```

Please see that there's a hidden input, where the concatenated URL is. What I'd like is to activate it while being hidden via a click of the `Go` button.

I'm really stuck with this now. I'd appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: Note that your HTML is invalid: `<input type="text" id="acturl" value=""/ hidden>` should be `<input type="text" id="acturl" value="" hidden>`. There is no need for the self-closing tag syntax.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about this! I'd fix it on my code from now on!~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the hidden input really needed?

Why not directly pass the `url` to the `iframe` source attribute?

```
$('#actpart1, #actpart2, #section10a').bind('keypress blur', function() {
  let url = 'https://sample.app/' + $('#actpart1').val() + '/' + $('#actpart2').val() + '.pdf';
  $('#actframe').attr('src', url);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this! And yes, I'd like to hide the url so that the users can easily change the values when they need to. Real thanks sir!

Answer (score 2):

You need to write `<input type="hidden" id="acturl" value="xxxx">` for a hidden input field (not `type="text"`), and include the value.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I'd do that now on my tool.